# Can a sequence of degree one maps converges to a constant map in $W^{1,2}$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis

Can a sequence of degree one maps on, say, the unit circle, converges to a constant map in $W^{1,2}$ norm?

If the answer is yes, would you please provide an explicit example?

Comment: No, it cannot. For the same reason that a sequence of continuous maps of non-zero degree cannot converge uniformly to a constant map.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? Someone told me the answer is YES in fact, without giving me an example.

Comment: I think they meant in higher dimensions where such a map need not be continuous.

Comment: Re Deane: Oh, do you have an example for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lift your map to the universal cover to obtain a function $f:R\to R$ satisfying
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+1,$$
if the degree is $1$. 
If the Sobolev norm of $f-c$ is $<\epsilon$ then by Schwarz inequality
$$(f(1)-f(0))^2\leq\int_0^1 (f'(t))^2dt<\epsilon,$$
which contradicts the first inequality if $\epsilon<1$.